# Understanding behavior of pandas join operator with how="right"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, indices

I need some help understanding the behavior of pandas "join" operator. When running the code below, I would expect a different output.

What bothers me is that the index column of the left dataframe gets turned into a column, which includes a value that was not there in the original left dataframe. Also, the new index has no name although it contains the same values as the previous "index_left". Why does pandas behave like this? Is my expectation wrong?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_left = pd.DataFrame(data=["value_left_1"], index=(["index_1"]), columns=["col_left_1"])
df_left.index.name = "index_left"
    
df_right = pd.DataFrame(data=[["value_right_1"],["value_right_2"]], index=(["index_1","index_2"]), columns=["col_right1"])
df_right.index.name = "index_right"
    
print(df_left.join(df_right, on="index_left", how="right"))
```

Actual output:

```
        index_left    col_left_1     col_right1
index_1    index_1  value_left_1  value_right_1
NaN        index_2           NaN  value_right_2
```

Expectation:

```
           col_left_1     col_right1
index_left
index_1    value_left_1  value_right_1
NaN        NaN           value_right_2
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired output, you may need to explicitly set the index to index_left:

import pandas as pd

```
df_left = pd.DataFrame(data=["value_left_1"], index=(["index_1"]), columns=["col_left_1"])
df_left.index.name = "index_left"
    
df_right = pd.DataFrame(data=[["value_right_1"],["value_right_2"]], index=(["index_1","index_2"]), columns=["col_right1"])
df_right.index.name = "index_right"
    
print(df_left.join(df_right, on="index_left", how="right").set_index('index_left'))
```

output:

```
             col_left_1     col_right1
index_left                             
index_1     value_left_1  value_right_1
index_2              NaN  value_right_2
```

Comment: I do not want to change the output afterwards, I try to understand why "index_left" becomes a column and contains values which were not there in the first place.

Comment: Join, by default, creates a new dataframe with the columns of both, left and right dataframes, and the join column(s) is/are also included in the output. "Right" also includes all the rows of the right dataframe and populates the non matching columns of the left dataframe with Null values. You can find more details here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: I understand that much. But this does not explain why "index_left" in the new data frame is a column while it was an index in df_left and why it suddenly contains the value "index_2", which is not a Null value but a new value.

Comment: Actually Index_left contains both, NAN and index_2, if you do df_left['index_left'] you will see both values. Also, by using "on" in the join we are saying that index_left is a column or index level according to the documentation. If we wanted the join index to index then we don't use the "on" , it should've been just n df_left.join(df_right,  how="right")